# Preview syntax highlighting from Telescope more accurate than in nvim buffer

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting within Telescope preview shows up better than inside neovim itself. From what I understand, the Telescope preview is based on what it would look like in an nvim buffer, so what am I missing?

I've tried the solution from [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34496/syntax-highlighting-is-incomplete-on-neovim-fixed-by-calling-telescope) by adding the following lines to my init.vim and sourcing but they have had no effect.

```
lua <<EOF
require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
  highlight = {
    enable = true,
  },
}
EOF
```

[syntax highlighting in Telescope preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grx5O.png)

[syntax highlighting outside Telescope preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NXN5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I discovered this plugin

https://github.com/nathom/filetype.nvim#customization

and set my filetype for .launch files to be .xml which fixed it.